# determining the radius of convergence for $a_n=n$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am asked to find the radius of convergence for the power series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$$ with $a_n=n$.

I should be using $r=(\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n})^{-1}$,

which would give me $\lim_{n\to\infty}|n^{1/n}|^{-1}$

where $n^{1/n}=\exp(\frac{\log n}{n})$.

$r=|\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(\frac{\log n}{n})|^{-1}$

using l'hospital

$r=|\exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n})|$

$r=\exp(0)=1$

Comment: $\frac {\log n} n \to 0$ by L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: In this case, the ratio test works more smoothly than the root test.

Comment: @geetha290krm I have made the necessary edits, does it look wright now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems okay. Only a small error is that you cannot replace $\limsup$ with $\lim$ before you know that the limits exists. You should have computed the limit and then said: since the limit exists it equals $\limsup$ which is equal to $r$.

Alternatively you could have used ratio test:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big\lvert \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\Big\rvert=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$$
Since the limit exists you have that $r=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big\lvert \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\Big\rvert=1$